# How to add multiple numbers to multiple lists

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to add multiple numbers to multiple lists.

I want to put the input to go in the the order:
Patient one: variable one, variable two, variable three
Patient two: variable one, variable two, variable three
Patient three: variable one, variable two, variable three

I have figured out how to get the information in the dictionaries, however in the wrong order.

But currently the order of input is:
Patient one: variable one, Patient two: variable one, Patient three: variable one
Patient one: variable two, Patient two: variable two, Patient three: variable two
Patient one: variable three, Patient two: variable three, Patient three: variable three

Any suggestions?

```
while True:
        print("")
        number_of_persons=(input("Please enter no. of persons \n"
         "Whole digit only. \n"
   "Positive Number:"))

        if number_of_persons.isdigit():
            print("Thanks")
            break
        try:
            pass
        except:
            pass

number_of_persons=int(number_of_persons)

variable_one = []
variable_two = []
variable_three = []

for person in range(0,number_of_persons):
    while True:
        print("Person Number: " ,person + 1)
        a=(input("     Enter variable one: "))

        if a.isdigit():
            print("Thanks")
            variable_one.append(a)
            break
        try:
            pass
        except:
            pass


for person in range(0,number_of_persons):
    while True:
        print("Person Number: " ,person + 1)
        b=(input("     Enter variable two: "))

        if b.isdigit():
            print("Thanks")
            variable_two.append(b)
            break
        try:
            pass
        except:
            pass


for person in range(0,number_of_persons):
    while True:
        print("Person Number: " ,person + 1)
        c=(input("     Enter variable Three: "))

        if c.isdigit():
            print("Thanks")
            variable_three.append(c)
            break
        try:
            pass
        except:
            pass        


print(variable_one)
print(variable_two)
print(variable_three)
```

Comment: "however in the wrong order"- I mean, you programmed it this way: you're iterating over people, and for each person ask the user to enter one kind of value, so the code works as intended. If you want to ask for multiple values for one person, iterate like this: `for person in range(...): for value_number in range(3): c=input(f"Enter variable {value_number}: ")`

Answer (score 1):

First, you are dealing with *lists*, not *dictionaries*. Here is one way by having a list of lists:

```
while True:
        print("")
        number_of_persons=(input("Please enter no. of persons \n"
         "Whole digit only. \n"
   "Positive Number: "))

        if number_of_persons.isdigit():
            print("Thanks")
            break

number_of_persons=int(number_of_persons)

variables = []
for i in range(number_of_persons):
    variables.append([]) # a list of lists

for person in range(number_of_persons):
    for n in range(3):
        while True:
            a = input(f"Person Number: {person + 1}, variable {n + 1}: ")
            if a.isdigit():
                print("Thanks")
                variables[person].append(a)
                break

print(variables)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a way using a dictionary.**

```
def input_number(i):
    while True:
        try:
            number = int(input(f"\tEnter variable {i+1}: "))
            print("\n")
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Only integers accepted!\n")
    return number


while True:
    try:
        print("Please enter no. of persons")
        print("Whole digit only.")
        number_of_persons = int(input("Positive number: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Only integers accepted!\n")


variables = {}
for person in range(number_of_persons):
    print("----------------------------------------")
    vars_ = []
    for i in range(number_of_persons):
        print(f"Person Number: {person + 1}")
        a = input_number(i)
        vars_.append(a)
    variables[person+1] = vars_


print("\n")
print(variables)
for j in range(len(variables)):
    print(variables[j+1])
```

**Sample output:**

```
Please enter no. of persons
Whole digit only.
Positive number: 2
----------------------------------------
Person Number: 1
    Enter variable 1: 50


Person Number: 1
    Enter variable 2: 100


----------------------------------------
Person Number: 2
    Enter variable 1: 150


Person Number: 2
    Enter variable 2: 200




{1: [50, 100], 2: [150, 200]}
[50, 100]
[150, 200]
```